# How do i pass a parameter to a function im calling in the SignalR connection.invoke method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I need to pass some data to the function i wanna render, but i dont know the syntax to do so.

Code:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hubFilas").build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    var time = setInterval(function () {
        connection.invoke("renderComponent").then(function (o) { DisplayHub(o) }).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    }, 120000)
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass the data as parameter to the `invoke` call. As described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-hub-methods-from-the-client) for sample hub:

```cs
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        => await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

You can invoke the method via following call:

```js
connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message);
```

Also check out:

- [SignalR API design considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/api-design?view=aspnetcore-7.0)